# how to update json file in ios during runtime from the server

Tags: ios, json

I want to update my `json` file in `ios app` which is offline compiled in the app. When the app is refreshed the file should get updated from the server : `localhost:8888/ios/ios_app/Service/data.json`

Please help...
Thank you in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to download and replace existing JSON file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22065038/how-to-download-and-replace-existing-json-file)

Answer (score 0):

I use SOAP when i need get value that can be serialized to a string type. But if all what you need is `json` file, look at `NSURLConnection` class.

```
- (void)downloadJSONFromURL {
    NSURLRequest *request = ....
    NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
    // ...
}

NSData *urlData;

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    urlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [urlData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
    id object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];

    if (jsonParsingError) {
        DLog(@"JSON ERROR: %@", [jsonParsingError localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        DLog(@"OBJECT: %@", [object class]);
    }
}
```